# BigQuery Error : Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to connect to MySQL database

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm currently facing an error while attempting to query a Cloud SQL database from BigQuery. The error message states:

> 'Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to connect to
> MySQL database. Error: MysqlErrorCode(2013): Lost connection to MySQL
> server during query at [1:15]'

I'm currently facing an error while attempting to query a Cloud SQL database (MySQL) from BigQuery. The error message states:

> 'Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to connect to
> MySQL database. Error: MysqlErrorCode(2013): Lost connection to MySQL
> server during query at [1:15]'

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this error.

Comment: see if this resolves your issue
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Big-Query-can-t-connect-to-Cloud-SQL/m-p/551847